# How to save a optional value in a variable to another non optional object

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

```
var ret: ServiceQuestion?

    ret = currentQuestion

    return ret ?? ServiceQuestion()
```

When i use it like above it works fine but when i change the code to

```
var ret = ServiceQuestion()

    ret = currentQuestion

    return ret
```

then it start giving error on the current question variable **Value of optional type 'ServiceQuestion?' not unwrapped;**

I need to implement the second way how can i get rid of this problem

error on console
Cityworks[8230:187999] [error] error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'ServiceRequestQuestion'
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't save an optional value in a non-optional var.

You have to unwrap it.

There are many many ways that this can be done.

The simplest (and most dangerous) is... `ret = currentQuestion!`.

But this will crash if `currentQuestion` is nil. You have to decide how you want to unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ret` is no longer optional, you can use its value in `??` operator:

```
var ret = ServiceQuestion()
ret = currentQuestion ?? ret
```

However, this would allocate `ServiceQuestion` that would remain unused when `currentQuestion` has value, so your first code snippet is more efficient. It is also easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **force unwrapping** for this:

```
return currentQuestion!
```

...but you **should not use force unwrapping**, only in really narrow and dedicated situations when you are absolutely sure the value will never be `nil`.

Why? Because if the value is `nil`, **your application will crash**. Consider **changing** the return value **to optional**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like that:-

```
var serviceQuestion = ServiceQuestion()
if let currentQuestion:ServiceQuestion = currentQuestion {
    serviceQuestion = currentQuestion 
}
return serviceQuestion
```

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70) giving this error .

Comment: Are you sure that your initialiser is correct, as this the complier error for bad memory allocation, Could you share the complete source of the function and error on the console

Answer (score 0):

```
var ret = ServiceQuestion()
    ret = currentQuestion
       return ret
```

You got this error because ret is non optional variable but currentQuestion is optional and you are assigning optional variable to non optional.

You need to do

```
var serviceQuestion = ServiceQuestion()
if let currentQuestion = currentQuestion {
    serviceQuestion = currentQuestion 
}
return serviceQuestion
```

or

```
var serviceQuestion = ServiceQuestion()
if currentQuestion != nil {
    serviceQuestion = currentQuestion!
}
return serviceQuestion
```

if you do this

```
var serviceQuestion = ServiceQuestion()
serviceQuestion = currentQuestion! 
return serviceQuestion
```

it might crash when currentQuestion is nil

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70) giving this error on  serviceQuestion = currentQuestion